# Why does Wordpress mysteriously run and additional invisible time (Twice with one output)

Tags: php, wordpress

So. I decided to remake my previous question for clarification.

**Background:**

- Plugin based on an MVC architecture.
- You can register users.
- A user need to activate their account.

**Problem:**

When one clicks on the link from the email that the user recieve they get to the correct page, get no php errors. But the account is already activated.
That is everything works exactly like the page is first run through but no output, then run through again and it is displayed to the user.

I have through var_dump, echo and print_r() determined that the account is activated before my plugin is even initialized, so its not a problem in my code..

**Codeflow:**

1. In the root of the plugin: `$controller = new Controller()`
2. Controller hooks `$controller->init()` to [init](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/init)
3. init() runs `$get_handler->handle($_GET)` where `$get_handler` is instanced in `$controller->__construct()`
4. The handler activates `$get_handler->activate()` when `$_GET['activation_key']` is set and not empty string

But as far as i can see this code is run **twice**, for no apparent reason.

I get 2 messages, wich is added into _SESSION until displayed.

The first saying the account is activated, the second saying that the account is already activated.

Is this how wordpress always does it? Is there a work around? How come I dont have this problem anywhere else on the site? Is there any Wordpress hooks that are run twice?

Edit:

Looks like its only when klicking the link from the mail, thus opening a new tab. If i reload the tab everything works fine. I'm using gmail, does gmail run the page before showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like i stumbled upon a solution.

There was a slash missing. A SLASH!

This link is correct:

```
http://www.page.com/permalink/?activation_key=2ad60f33
                             ^
```

This link triggers dual messages:

```
http://www.page.com/permalink?activation_key=2ad60f33
```